# Craft Install Hangs on Locale Record

Tags: install

Installing Craft-2.4.2723 on Centos 6.5 MySql 5.6.27 PHP 5.4.45 gets hung in 'Oops' monkey screen. Minimum requirements are met. Permissions are wide open. Database exists but no tables are created. Collation is set to `utf8_unicode_ci`. Following is craft.log:

```
2015/11/13 21:51:08 [warning] [application] Skipping record /var/www/craft/app/records/BaseRecord.php because it’s abstract or an interface.

2015/11/13 21:51:08 [error] [exception.ReflectionException] exception 'ReflectionException' with message 'Class Craft\EntryLocaleRecord does not exist' in /var/www/craft/app/services/InstallService.php:125

Stack trace: 0 /var/www/craft/app/services/InstallService.php(125): ReflectionClass->__construct('Craft\\EntryLoca...')
1 /var/www/craft/app/services/InstallService.php(47): Craft\InstallService->findInstallableRecords()
2 /var/www/craft/app/controllers/InstallController.php(159): Craft\InstallService->run(Array)
3 /var/www/craft/app/framework/web/actions/CInlineAction.php(49): Craft\InstallController->actionInstall()
4 /var/www/craft/app/framework/web/CController.php(308): CInlineAction->runWithParams(Array)
5 /var/www/craft/app/framework/web/CController.php(286): CController->runAction(Object(CInlineAction))
6 /var/www/craft/app/framework/web/CController.php(265): CController->runActionWithFilters(Object(CInlineAction), Array)
7 /var/www/craft/app/framework/web/CWebApplication.php(282): CController->run('install')
8 /var/www/craft/app/etc/web/WebApp.php(805): CWebApplication->runController('install/install')#9 /var/www/craft/app/etc/web/WebApp.php(772): Craft\WebApp->_processActionRequest()
10 /var/www/craft/app/etc/web/WebApp.php(193): Craft\WebApp->_processInstallRequest()
11 /var/www/craft/app/framework/base/CApplication.php(184): Craft\WebApp->processRequest()
12 /var/www/craft/app/index.php(62): CApplication->run()
13 /var/www/html/index.php(19): require_once('/var/www/craft/...')
14 {main}

REQUEST_URI=/index.php/admin/actions/install/install
HTTP_REFERER=http://myserver.com/index.php/admin/install

2015/11/13 21:51:08 [error] [application] Class Craft\EntryLocaleRecord does not exist
```

It appears that it's not being passed the 'Locale' record. Any ideas on this?

Answer (score 1):

Does `EntryLocaleRecord.php` exist in `craft/app/records`?  My guess is that it didn't copy/FTP up to your server properly or its corrupted.

I'd try re-uploading the entire `craft/app` folder to make sure there aren't others missing.

Comment: Yep, that was it...I compared against a known working system, and sure 'nuf missing some files in the craft/app folder.  Re-downloaded from Craft site, unzipped, and installed w/success.

Comment: For future reference it may be helpful to note that the systemwide locale variable being picked up by Craft is in /etc/sysconfig/i18n. Good call, Brad, Thanks!